# System freezes for a few seconds when pressing certain keys Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, freeze

After having used my computer for a few days, it started to freeze occasionally for a few seconds when I pressed certain buttons. Even when this started to happen I was not able figure out how to reproduce this phenomenon reliably. It seems to me that this was more likely to happen when I pressed keys (or combination of keys) to which certain tasks were assigned (like brightness keys or shortcuts). Also it always happened once for each button. (So for instance I pressed the mute key then it froze but after that I didn't freeze when I pressed it again.)

Logging out and logging in again resolves the issue (no reboot needed). I only experienced this problem in the XFCE environment, but I don't know if this bug is specific to it.

Comment: I have the same  freezes (of 5s to 10s each) for a few weeks now, since I upgraded to xubuntu 20.04.

To help find the root cause I have noticed these :
1) when I press luminosity shortcut keys (fn + arrow)
2) when I use my xbox controler. 
3) when I plug my yubikey (which as I know may show itself to the computer as a keyboard)
4) When re-press any regular key after having triggered the freeze with one of the previous methods. 

TLDR: Each time, it seems that it's switching from a key input source to another that trigger the freeze.

Comment: Having the same thing. Keyboard freezes (not mouse). Then it may re-type the same character many times even though I know I didn't hold it. I have XFCE 20.04.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when I use any of the fn keys, to adjust brightness or volume, etc... it freezes for like two seconds.

Comment: Same issue, especially with volume controls, in Xubuntu 20.04.  I disabled the volume OSD but that made no difference.  Rebooting fixes it for a while.  It can also happen when using the arrow keys to adjust volume in a youtube video, or simply when alt-tabbing when there's a video or videogame running.